# Why does Celery give No such file or directory error?

Tags: django, email, celery, wkhtmltopdf

I generate a PDF and send it through email as attachment. Whenever I run `celery multi start worker -A erp -l info` and try to send the email it works. But whenever I do it with the daemonized Celery it shows the following error.

```
[2018-05-11 20:53:47,131: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-6] Task europarts.tasks.generate_pdf_and_send_email[fd80843b-647c-412e-b847-f35cbf157fae] raised unexpected: OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "europarts/tasks.py", line 58, in generate_pdf_and_send_email
    email.attach(file_name, response.rendered_content, 'application/pdf')
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 78, in rendered_content
    cmd_options=cmd_options
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 186, in render_pdf_from_template
    cmd_options=cmd_options)
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 124, in convert_to_pdf
    return wkhtmltopdf(pages=filename, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michel/erp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 110, in wkhtmltopdf
    return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can see that on line 58 I have and error in my function. But that function does not write a file to disk, just creates the PDF and attaches it to email before sending. Here is the code:

```
def generate_pdf_and_send_email(template, filename, context, pk, model, subject, body, from_email, to):
    request = RequestFactory().get(reverse('europarts:{model}_email'.format(model=model), args=[pk]))

    kw = {
        '{model}_id'.format(model=model): pk
    }
    row_model = '{model}Row'.format(model=model)
    rows = apps.get_model('europarts', row_model).objects.filter(**kw)
    context['{model}_rows'.format(model=model)] = rows
    file_name = '{model}_email.pdf'.format(model=model)

    response = PDFTemplateResponse(
        request=request,
        template=template,
        filename=filename,
        context=context,
        show_content_in_browser=True,
        cmd_options={'margin-top': 10,
                     'zoom': 1,
                     'viewport-size': '1366 x 513',
                     'javascript-delay': 1000,
                     'no-stop-slow-scripts': True},
    )

    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = subject
    email.body = body
    email.from_email = from_email
    email.to = to
    email.attach(file_name, response.rendered_content, 'application/pdf')

    email.send()

    return response
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried with `absolute path`?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I don't know what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MiniGunnR the first comment probably means if you tried specifying the absolute path for `file_name` instead of just `file_name = '{model}_email.pdf'.format(model=model)`. Maybe something like `file_name = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file_name)` after the first assignment of `file_name`.

Comment: @Ralf I've done that. It still doesn't work. There are not many resources on the Internet with this problem. It seems like a rare error for something like this.

Comment: @Ralf When I try the same code without celery it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by finding out where `wkhtmltopdf` was installed:

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

And putting that location in `settings.py`:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```